# Homology and Homotopy in the Plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology

Suppose we're living in the plane minus (possibly infinitely many) isolated points, which I'll call poles. Intuitively, the following two statements seem reasonable:

1. Loops in the plane are homotopic iff their interior contains the same poles.
2. Loops in the plane are homotopic iff they are homologous.

Are these statements true? Why and/or why not?

***Edit:***

I forgot about winding numbers, so I'd like to expand on statement 1:
Does it hold if the winding number of each pole is no greater than 1 in absolute value, *and* the loop does not intersect itself? Same goes for statement 2.

***Edit 2:***

I asked about the edited version of question 2 separately.

Comment: What is a "loop" to you? The answer is different depending on what definition you are using.

Comment: I was thinking continuous image of an interval with endpoints at the same point. What other useful notions of loop are there?

Comment: If that is your definition, question 1 makes no sense. A continuous map of the interval with endpoints at the same point does not have a well-defined notion of "interior".

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that just a closed curve? I mean the endpoints of the "image", not the original interval.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_contour is a counterxample of 2.  I don't know what happens if you insist on non-self intersection.

Comment: If the loop doesn't intersect itself then I think it's already true that the winding number can't be greater than $1$ in absolute value around any pole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding question 1, even two non-self-intersecting curves that enclose the same sets of points with winding number 1 might not be homotopic:

[image: non-homotopic curves]

Comment: I'll wait for a bit to see whether anyone answers question 2 aswell. If not, I'll ask it separately and accept this answer.

Comment: These two loops (red and blue) are not homotopic. Are they homologous?

Answer (score 4):

The first statement is not true, even for the plane minus finitely many (even one) point. Assuming we know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0) = \mathbb{Z}$, generated by loops around $0$, then the double winding around $0$ and the single winding around $0$ both contain the same "pole" but are not homotopic.

Comment: Ah, of course I stupidly ignored winding numbers. I'm also interested in the case where the maximal absolute value of the winding number of each pole is no greater than 1. I'll edit my question.

Comment: That's still not good enough because if there are two points, a figure 8 and a circle are not homotopic.

Comment: Ah! Right, what if the curve does not intersect itself either?

Comment: Still not good enough. Imagine 3 points in a horizontal row. Curve 1 goes above all points and then loops down to enclose the left and right point but not the middle. Curve 2 goes below all points and then loops up to enclose the left and right point but not the middle. Both contain the left and right point and not the middle but I'm pretty sure they aren't homotopic.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Now what have you got to say about statement 2? :p

Comment: @Exterior I haven't thought about it. I'll post my comment on question 1 as an answer and let others answer question 2.

Answer (score 4):

Without non-self-intersection, the first statement is already false for the plane minus one point, and the second statement is already false for the plane minus two points. In fact, the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus $k$ points is the [free group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) on $k$ generators (so free homotopy classes of loops correspond to conjugacy classes in the free group), and for $k = 2$ a commutator in this group (which describes the [Pochhammer contour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_contour), as mentioned by Jason DeVito in the comments) is both null-homologous and has zero winding number around every point, but is not null-homotopic.