# Homology and Homotopy in the Plane II

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This question arose from [Homology and Homotopy in the Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046762/homology-and-homotopy-in-the-plane), where it was one of several questions asked (but not answered). I'm posting it separately so I could accept one of the answers there.

*Is the following statement true?*

> In the plane with isolated points removed (possibly infinitely many), two simple (non-self-intersecting) loops are homotopic iff they are homologous.

Here, "loop" means a continuous image of a closed interval, with endpoints at the same point.

Comment: This is false, as is already shown in the answer to your earlier question that you accepted. Is there something about that answer that you do not understand?

Comment: I don't understand where the falseness of this statement was shown in answers to my earlier question. The answers addressed the possibly self-intersecting case.

Comment: The falseness comes from the fact that two curves in a multipunctured plane are homologous if and only if they have the same winding number around each puncture.

Comment: @LeeMosher how would I go on to prove this?

Comment: It's a basic example of algebraic topology that the first homology of a multipunctured plane is a free abelian group with a basis represented one cycle for each puncture, going once around that puncture in the counterclockwise direction.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of this.